# Openshift Kafka Connect Project access through Postman

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, apache-kafka-connect

I wanted to create kafka connect connector on openshift project through postman. But when sending Post command  through postman getting error as below. In openshift to expose pod as a service(interact through postman) any specific command we need to run? Please advise.

---

Possible reasons you are seeing this page:

The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.

The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.

Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.

---

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you havent created any route to interact with the required service.

In openshift a service is exposed to the applications outside of cluster through routes.

Use the following command to expose service outside of cluster :
oc expose service

You can include many options with the above command . to know more use the following command
oc expose service --help